# Complex heapq lazy merge (minimize space used)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a list of sorted lists, I wish to produce a sorted list of output.

This would be easy:

```
nums : List[List[int]]
h = heapq.merge(nums)
```

However, I also wish to tag each element of the output, with the index of the inner list from which it originated. Eg.

```
nums = [[1,3,5], [2,6], [4]]
h = _ # ???
for x in h:
    print(x)

# Outputs
# (1,0)
# (2,1)
# (3,0)
# (4,2)
# (5,0)
# (6,1)
```

I have written a version that works,

`h = heapq.merge(*map(lambda l: map(lambda x: (x,l[0]), l[1]), enumerate(nums)))`

But I'm afraid I might have lost a desirable space-complexity guarantee; how can I know whether the (transformed) inner lists are being manifested or not? (and what exactly does the `*` do in my attempt?)

Comment: `heapq.merge` isn't constant-space in the first place. It takes space proportional to the number of iterables to merge. That's usually a lot lower than the total number of elements, but it's not constant.

Comment: Also, passing `function(*some_iterator)` will consume the whole iterator and expand into args  when the function is called.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica thanks, I realized after posting that it wasn't the best wording, have edited

Answer (score 0):

Since default tuple comparison is lexicographic, you can convert the innermost-element `x` to `(x, i)` where `i` is the index of the list containing `x` in `nums`. For example,

```
import heapq
from itertools import repeat

nums = [[1,3,5], [2,6], [4]]
nums_with_inds = (zip(lst, repeat(i)) for i, lst in enumerate(nums))

res = heapq.merge(*nums_with_inds)
for tup in res:
  print(tup)

# (1, 0)
# (2, 1)
# (3, 0)
# (4, 2)
# (5, 0)
# (6, 1)
```

Comment: This performs the materialization the questioner wanted to avoid.

Comment: Fair enough, I've misread the end of the question. My guess is the updated iterator-based implementation fits the requirement.

Comment: 1) Does my version materialize? 2) Given a version, how best to check whether it materializes or not? (Other than reasoning about the semantics of the code)